# Fix script editor script for applescript

Tags: performance, optimization, applescript, helper

I am creating a small program and one of my functions is a dictionary. I need a way to split the subjects though but for some reason my code won't work. I keep getting the error "Expected “else”, etc. but found “end tell”." for this code:

```applescript
set math_list to {"math", "Math"}
set science_list to {"science", "Science"}
set history_list to {"History", "history", "Social Studies", "social studies", "socialstudies"}
set reading_list to {"writing", "reading", "grammar", "Grammar", "Reading"}
set no_list to {"no", "not really", "I am ok", "I am good", "I am good"}
set complete_list to reading_list & math_list & science_list & no_list & history_list

tell application "SpeechRecognitionServer"
    set theResponse to listen for complete_list with prompt "Would you like to search under the subject math, science, history, or reading"
        if theResponse = "writing" then
            set theResponse to "reading" --Otherwise you would get a very weird sentence
        else if theResponse = "grammar" then
            set theResponse to "reading" --Otherwise you would get a very weird sentence
    if (math_list contains theResponse) then
        say "Opening Google Chrome"
        launch application "Google Chrome"
    else if (science_list contains theResponse) then
        say "Opening Google Chrome"
        launch application "Google Chrome"
    else if (history_list contains theResponse) then
        say "Opening Google Chrome"
        launch application "Google Chrome"
    else if (reading_list contains theResponse) then
        say "Opening Google Chrome"
        launch application "Google Chrome"
    else if (no_list contains theResponse) then
        say "Ok then"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

You will also find that simply typing end at the conclusion of a repeat, tell, or if section will automatically be compiled into the correct type of end needed:

```
tell app "itunes"
repeat 5 times
if exists playlist "Purchased" then
play track 7 of playlist "Purchased"
end
end
end
```

is subsequently compiled into:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat 5 times
        if exists playlist "Purchased" then
            play track 7 of playlist "Purchased"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Learning to use that style of entering code will speed up your production and greatly reduce errors and problems.

Good luck,

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An `if else` block ends with `end if`. Not with `end tell`.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer that worked for me. Thank you Craig Smith:

You will also find that simply typing end at the conclusion of a repeat, tell, or if section will automatically be compiled into the correct type of end needed:

tell app "itunes"
repeat 5 times
if exists playlist "Purchased" then
play track 7 of playlist "Purchased"
end
end
end
is subsequently compiled into:

tell application "iTunes"
    repeat 5 times
        if exists playlist "Purchased" then
            play track 7 of playlist "Purchased"
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
Learning to use that style of entering code will speed up your production and greatly reduce errors and problems.

Good luck,